# Using multiprocessing to share messages between processes on different modules

Tags: python, tkinter, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to run a GUI on a separate process from my "main" program while still being able to retrieve values from the GUI in the "main" module.

Right now I have a simple GUI setup with a simple function on the "main" module to get several values triggered by a button press.

I have instantiated both classes in my "main" module but after I start the GUI process, press the 'start' button to trigger my retrieve & print function I receive the following error:

```
NameError: name 'start' is not defined
```

"main" module:

```
#############################
#### Importing Libraries ####
#############################

from GUI import *

#############################
#### Creating Main Class ####
#############################

class Round_Sling_Main:

    def sling_start(self):
        current_length = start.get_length()
        current_speed = start.get_speed()
        current_color = start.get_color()
        print(current_length, current_speed, current_color)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    round_sling = Round_Sling_Main()
    start = GUI(round_sling, 0, 0, "").start()
```

GUI module:

```
#############################
#### Importing Libraries ####
#############################

import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sys
from multiprocessing import Process

############################
#### Creating Front GUI ####
############################

class GUI(Process):

    def __init__(self, round_sling, length, speed, color):
        super(GUI, self).__init__()
        self.round_sling = round_sling
        self.length = length
        self.speed = speed
        self.color = color
        self.create_GUI()

    def retrieve_length(self, length):
        self.length = length

    def retrieve_speed(self, speed):
        self.speed = speed

    def retrieve_color(self, event = None):
        self.color = event.widget.get()

    def get_length(self):
        return self.length

    def get_speed(self):
        return self.speed

    def get_color(self):
        return self.color

    def close(self):
        sys.exit()

    def create_GUI(self):
        while(1):

            front = tk.Tk()
            front.title ("Round Sling Machine")
            front.geometry ('800x600')
            #front.config (cursor = 'none')
            #front.attributes ("-fullscreen", True)

            # Color Selection Label
            Color_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Select a Sling Color', font = 'Verdana 12')
            Color_Label.place(x = 300, y = 0)

            # Material Selection Label
            Material_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Select a Sling Material', font = 'Verdana 12')
            Material_Label.place(x = 300, y = 80)

            # Length Entry Label
            Length_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Select Desired Sling Length (inches)', font = 'Verdana 12')
            Length_Label.place(x = 240,y = 160)

            # Speed Factor Label
            Speed_Label = tk.Label (front, text = 'Enter Motor Speed Factor (0.0 - 1.0)', font = 'Verdana 8')
            Speed_Label.place(x = 25, y = 35)

            # Color Selection Combo Box
            ColorVar = tk.StringVar()
            SlingColor = ttk.Combobox(front, width = 27, textvariable = ColorVar)
            SlingColor['values'] = ('Purple',
                                    'Green',
                                    'Yellow',
                                    'Tan',
                                    'Red',
                                    'White',
                                    'Blue',
                                    'Orange 1',
                                    'Orange 2',
                                    'Orange 3',
                                    'Orange 4',
                                    'Orange 5',
                                    'Orange 6')
            SlingColor.state(["readonly"])
            SlingColor.place(x = 300, y = 30)

            SlingColor.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", self.retrieve_color)

            # Material Selection Combo Box
            MaterialVar = tk.StringVar()
            MaterialSel = ttk.Combobox(front, width = 27, textvariable = MaterialVar)
            MaterialSel['values'] = ('Nylon', 'Polyester', 'Carbon Fiber')
            MaterialSel.state(["readonly"])
            MaterialSel.place(x = 300, y = 110)

            # Sling Length Slider
            SlingLength = tk.Scale(front, from_ = 0, to = 100, length = 600, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = self.retrieve_length)
            SlingLength.place(x = 105, y = 190)

            # Motor Speed Factor Slider
            MotorSpeed = tk.Scale(front, from_ = 0, to = 1.0, resolution = 0.1, length = 200, orient=tk.HORIZONTAL, command = self.retrieve_speed)
            MotorSpeed.place(x = 25, y = 50)

            startBtn = tk.Button(front, text = 'Start', font = 'Verdana 12', command = self.round_sling.sling_start)
            startBtn.place(x = 250, y = 250)

            closeBtn = tk.Button(front, text = 'Close', font = 'Verdana 12', command = self.close)
            closeBtn.place(x = 450, y = 250)

            front.mainloop()

############################
##### End of Front GUI #####
############################
```

Comment: This is not a good design.  The big problem here is that `tk.mainloop()` does not return until the program exits.  Thus, you will never return from `GUI.__init__`.  There's nothing to start.  More importantly, you don't really want to spread a GUI across multiple processes.  Remember that those processes have totally separate address spaces.  They don't share memory.  You need to step back and design this in a way that works with GUi frameworks.

Comment: Actually I think the big problem is better described as because `GUI.__init__()` calls `create_GUI()` which is an infinite `while(1):` loop which creates a `Tk` instance and calls its `mainloop()` each iteration. Besides that having a `0%` chance of working, the proper way to subclass the `multiprocessing.Process` class is to override its `run()` method as described in its [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Process).

Comment: The responses thus far are about as poor as my programming ability which is essentially non-existent. Remember, we come to forums like this for assistance not spotlighting the problem at hand. "Step back and design this in a way that works." Is about as useful as a poopy flavored lollipop.

Comment: For anyone coming here for functional assistance there is a Shared Memory class that can be used for sharing memory between processes. I'll try that and edit the post.

Comment: Raudert, I understand your frustration but in fact the first two comments are telling you something that you need to know.  You have asked a question about sharing memory between processes, an advanced subject.  But your code is failing because of basic Python/tkinter issues that must be addressed first.  There is no point in discussing memory sharing until the basic framework of your program is sound.  And by the way, the Shared Memory class is not going to have any bearing on the NameError that you are seeing.

Comment: Paul, thank you very much for your reply. I spent some time last night working on just that and quickly realized my efforts there were for naught as well. I've just started Python, programming in general, maybe a month ago so this is all new to me unfortunately. I'll dial it back a bit and revert to using multithreading which I had working quite well.